# Angular 1.5.8 input custom directive ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been struggling and Googling everywhere around and I can't imagine why this directive doesn't update my controller $scope value:
Directive:

```
app.directive('ingFormField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            value: "=",
            fieldName: "@",
            fieldLabel: "@"
        },
        div class="form-group">'+
            '   <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="control-label">{{fieldLabel}}:</label>'+
            '   <input ng-model="value" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{fieldName}}" id="{{fieldName}}" />' +
        '</div>'
    };
});
```

used in HTML:

```
    <ing-form-field field-name="Order" field-label="Order" ng-model="lateral.Order"></ing-form-field>
```

And my object "lateral" from my controller:

```
$scope.lateral = {Order: "01", Name: "Person"}
```

I've tried some functions from StackOverflow answers about using a link function to update values in my controller $scope with the same output: values from $scope to the directive are working but any change on the directive's input field don't update $scope object "lateral"

Comment: could you add the html parent code where you placed this directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be has an alternative aproach by using `ngModel` parameter directly and pass it through your template. Using `ngModel` will help you to keep consistence of naming things on your template.

For example, if you use your directive template using the `ngModel` directive, you can call it from the directive scope and use it do reflect the model to your parent controller.

The following code implement this solution, be aware that this is one of the solution, you may find different ways to do that.

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .directive('ingFormField', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {
        ngModel: "=",
        fieldName: "@",
        fieldLabel: "@"
      },
      template: '<div class="form-group">' +
        '   <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="control-label">{{fieldLabel}}:</label>' +
        '   <input ng-model="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{fieldName}}" id="{{fieldName}}" />' +
        '</div>'
    };
  })
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.lateral = {
      Order: "01",
      Name: "Person"
    }
  });

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="myController">
  <ing-form-field field-name="Order" field-label="Order" ng-model="lateral.Order">
  </ing-form-field>

  <pre>{{ lateral | json }}</pre>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code, you're very close. I think you may have been trying to set/pass the value using ngModel instead of the scoped property you designated for it, which was value. That's if I'm understanding correctly. Please let me know if this helps, if not I can always update.

```js
function exampleController($scope) {
  $scope.lateral = {
    Order: "01",
    Name: "Person"
  };
}

function ingFormField() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      value: "=",
      fieldName: "@",
      fieldLabel: "@"
    },
    template: '<div class="form-group"> ' +
      '   <label for="{{fieldName}}" class="control-label">{{fieldLabel}}:</label>' +
      '   <input ng-model="value" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{fieldName}}" id="{{fieldName}}" />' +
      '</div>'
  };
}

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .controller('exampleController', exampleController)
  .directive('ingFormField', ingFormField);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" ng-app="example">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <ing-form-field field-name="Order" field-label="Order" value="lateral.Order"></ing-form-field>

  </div>
</div>
```